# Converting Vietnamese html characters for csv file

Tags: php, html, csv, unicode

I am retrieving text from database that contains Vietnamese html characters, like:

```
driver &#272;&#7894;
```

which displays correctly on website as

```
driver ĐỖ
```

But I also need to save that data to a ';' delimited csv file that user can download. Obviously this causes problems because of the ; and because it is not translated back to something readable by the user.

I have no influence on how the data is stored in the database, so I need to find a conversion for those html carasters.

Comment: Which language are you using? A simple ‘XML/HTML decode’ function should suffice.

Comment: I am using PHP for this

Comment: Use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), and/or a CSV library that can quote values.

Comment: I tried html_entity_decode() already. It doesnt change its values.

Comment: *How* did you try it? You are aware that it *returns* a decoded string, right?

Comment: $dr = html_entity_decode($row["drivername"]);
fwrite($myfile1, $dr .";");

Comment: And what are the values of `$row["drivername"]` and `$dr`?

Comment: Found solution:
I had:
$dr = mb_convert_encoding($row["drivername"], "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");

but with
mb_convert_encoding($row["drivername"], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
it works
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Tried right now. It only adds quotes before and after the field.

Comment: Semicolon in quotes is not the same semicolon between fields. Use fgetcsv to see that there is everything ok.